# How do I approach existing questions to which I believe the answers are inadequate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've come across this problem recently when trying to find a solution to a problem on Stack Overflow. It was a common question to which there were already literally dozens of highly rated answers.

In my view, these answers were not good, or did not address the question (in this case the solutions simply didn't work for me).

I have gone about this by posting my own question, outlining why the answers didn't work, and hoping for a response. Is this how things should be done? For anyone interested, here is my new question:

[How do I import from a relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650531/how-do-i-import-from-a-relative-path)

Comment: You should have added explanation which of the original answers you have tried and how did they failed you. Except that you are probably good - if answers needs to be different, probably question is different, too ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Where existing answers are well recieved

If the answers appear highly rated (or even accepted) but don't work for you then it is likely that your question is subtly different; don't just re-ask the question but identify what it is about those answers that make them unsuitable for your situation then ask a question about that; linking the original question and explaining how yours is different.

If you see comments to back it up you could also edit the existing question to make it more specific to the answers given, but tred carefully not to change the existing question or invalidate existing answers. If making a suggested edit be sure to mention that you are including details from the comments

#### Where existing answers are not well recieved

On the other hand if the existing answers appear not to have been well recieved then it is likely that the questions are the same but no-one has provided a good answer as yet. In this case the appropriate thing to do is offer a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) stating why the existing answers are unsuitable

Answer (score 4):

Instead of posting a duplicate question. You can offer a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on one of the existing questions and ask for the addition information you want or state your problem with the existing answers.